# DOMElement nodeValue inconsistant get vs set

Tags: php, dom

I have just discovered that when reading the nodeValue from a DOMElement it returns the raw value (i.e. not encoded) but when you set the value you must encode it first or it truncates the text at the first invalid entity.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$element_p = $doc->createElement('p'); // DOMElement
$element_p->nodeValue = 'This & that.');
print($element_p->nodeValue); // 'This '

$element_p->nodeValue = 'This &amp; that.');
print($element_p->nodeValue); // 'This & that.'

// Setting it to itself truncates the text!
$element_p->nodeValue = $element_p->nodeValue;
print($element_p->nodeValue); // 'This '

// Encode before setting, don't decode after getting
$element_p->nodeValue = htmlspecialchars('This & that.');
print($element_p->nodeValue); // 'This & that.'

// Using htmlspecialchars() preserves the original text
$element_p->nodeValue = htmlspecialchars($element_p->nodeValue);
print($element_p->nodeValue); // 'This & that.'
```

Is this expected behaviour? Because it surprised me when I discovered it!

Comment: Yes that is to be expected AFAIK, because you actually should append a textnode instead. so `$element_p->appendChild($doc->createTextNode('This & that'));`

Comment: @PeeHaa That must be what I'm doing elsewhere in the code because I don't remember having to use `htmlspecialchars()` to get it to work before and I'm using _a lot_ of characters that need to be converted to entities. I still find it somewhat surprising that get and set are not in the same format. But then again, it is PHP!

Comment: In this specific case it is not so much PHP as it is DOM though ;)